# Dot over column vector

Tags: math-mode, vector

I create column vectors using:

```
\newcommand*\colvec[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
```

How do I put a "dot" above the vector?

```
\colvec{q\\ f(q, \dot{q}, u)}
```

I mean, I don't want `\dot` to be visually applied to each element of the column vector, but rather a single dot at the top of the column vector.

Comment: `\overset{\boldsymbol{.}}{\colvec{q\\ f(q, \dot{q}, u)}}`?

Answer (score 4):

I am generally not a big fan of such notation (nor of macros like `\colvec` which do nothing an editor with short-cuts cannot do more quickly), but you may use `\overset`. Most likely the size of a dot from `\dot` will be too tiny, i.e. may easily be missed by the reader. So maybe you could do one of those

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand*\colvec[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
\begin{document}
\[\overset{\boldsymbol{.}}{\colvec{q\\ f(q, \dot{q}, u)}}
=:\colvec{\dot q\\ F(q, \dot{q},\ddot{q}, u,\dot{u})}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\frac{\diff}{\diff t}\begin{pmatrix}q\\ f(q, \dot{q}, u)\end{pmatrix}
=:\begin{pmatrix}q\\ F(q, \dot{q},\ddot{q}, u,\dot{u})\end{pmatrix}
\]
\[
\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\bullet}{\colvec{q\\ f(q, \dot{q}, u)}}
=:\colvec{\dot q\\ F(q, \dot{q},\ddot{q}, u,\dot{u})}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\frac{\diff}{\diff t}\begin{pmatrix}q\\ f(q, \dot{q}, u)\end{pmatrix}
=:\begin{pmatrix}q\\ F(q, \dot{q},\ddot{q}, u,\dot{u})\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the size of the dots. This post is also to raise the question whether this notation is something many readers will find very useful.